# How to test a new value with all records from another table in PostegreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I want a trigger function that tests if new value (just for one column) exist in another column from another table.

Basically I have a table : `netgeo_cable_test` where I want to test if a new value inserted into the column `geom` exists in the colum `geom` from the table `netgeo_point_tech`.

I wanted to try a loop like an array but the result from a `SELECT` it is not an array.

I don't know how to do to be able to test each records from a column.

Comment: Do you want to see if it does exist or does not exist?  If you just want to make sure it exists, you should use a foreign key.  You definitely don't want to use a loop.

Comment: @Jeremy I want to test if it does not exist

Comment: IMHO your problem is similar to the [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159424/how-to-use-function-parameters-in-dynamic-sql-with-execute] question. The only thing which will be included is a line like `_testCond: int = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM netgeo_point_tech WHERE geom=$1` Where I am assuming that the first parameter is the `geom`. Then before, executing the sql enclose in the line `IF _testCond == 0 THEN EXECUTE _sql
      USING   $1, .... $n END IF;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following adapt as per your need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_records_netgeo_cable_test(
    _geom text
    , _fld2 text
    , _fld3 text
)
RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
DECLARE
    /* _testCond int; */
    _sql   text := 'INSERT INTO netgeo_cable_test (geom, fld2, fld3)
        VALUES($1, $2, $3)'; -- PREPARED SQL
BEGIN
    /* SELECT COUNT(*) INTO _testCond FROM netgeo_point_tech WHERE geom = $1;
    ### IF _testCond == 0 THEN */
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM netgeo_point_tech WHERE geom = $1) THEN
        EXECUTE _sql
            USING   $1, $2, $3; -- EXECUTE PREPARED SQL Wt VALUES
        RETURN true;  -- boolean!
    ELSE
        RETURN FALSE; -- boolean for failed test Cond
    END IF;
 RAISE NOTICE 'sql: %', _sql;

 END
 $func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Hope this helps for more information see the following [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159424/how-to-use-function-parameters-in-dynamic-sql-with-execute]

Comment: Doing a count is not efficient because it will check the whole table/index. You don't actually care about the count, only whether a record exists. You want the query to return as soon as it finds a single record. Therefore you should do `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ... ) THEN ...`

Comment: @404 updated :) have kept both options (one in comment) if the size of the table is small both can be used.

Comment: @AmitabhDas So if I understand this function will return true or false depending if the value exists or not, right ? 
I don't understand the `EXECUTE` part, what does it do ?

Comment: @LyessD The `EXECUTE` [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-execute.html] command is used to execute a prepared statement. The `_sql` variable we precook the SQL Statement and then execute it with substituting the values (`USING` keyword). As such it will return true, so that you can handle in your codes. Also if error, it will raise an error while printing the error `_sql`. As such in this, 
- we pass all the required field values as parameters
- we pre-cook the SQL statement
- we test the condition required to insert, if true 
- EXECUTE the precooked SQL
- Raise notice if err

Comment: Updated the Codes above to now send Both `true` and `false`  and have added more comments for you to better understand. Hope this helps